# how to send multipart form data from jsp to web service?

Tags: java, rest, jsp, servlets, jax-rs

I'm trying to create a Signup page for my website. 
When the user submits the data to signup.jsp, I want to send this data to my web service using "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". How can I do this in JSP. Tried following code but this sends data in the form of raw data.

```
<%    URL url = new URL("http://www.externalsite.com/sample.html");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    String postParams = "foo="+req.getParameter("foo");

    DataOutputStream paramsWriter = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    paramsWriter.writeBytes(postParams);
    paramsWriter.flush();
    paramsWriter.close();

    InputStream remoteResponse = conn.getInputStream();
    OutputStream localResponder = resp.getOutputStream();
    int c;
    while((c = remoteResponse.read()) != -1)
        localResponder.write(c);
    remoteResponse.close();
    localResponder.close();

    conn.disconnect(); %>
```

Comment: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" != multipart. Aside from that, what have you tried?

Comment: Just use one of the many higher level http client libraries.

Comment: Please give an example.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear at all what you want. Your title says multipart. Your post says application/x-www-form-urlencoded (which is not the same as mulitpart). Your code shows you're trying to use a Java client. You're asking about JSP to server. This all adds up to nonsense for me.

Comment: This is pretty typical. http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/ Although if it might be simpler to just parse your form and send structured data, say, JSON, to your service. There are others, though, just google it.

Comment: What do you mean by Raw data?Also what does user input consist of files/generic fields?

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal I mean Not as key-value pairs. all the fields are strings.

Answer (score 1):

In action tag of form just give url of the web service . The content-type is determined by  `enctype` attribute on form

If your form contains file input element then form opeaning tag should be like this

```
<form method="POST" action="<your web service address>" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

If it contains only text and other inputs except file than `enctype` will be

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

form more info refer

[java ee file upload example](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html)