# How to insert data into DB taking inputs from JSP and storing it using spring restful services,

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My JSP code is: feedback.jsp

Customer Feedback

```
        <tr><th>Name</th><td>
                    <spring:bind path="cust.name">
                    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" class="form-control" value="${pdet.register_fname}&nbsp;${pdet.register_lname}" pattern="[A-Za-z\s]{1,15}"
                            title="Name should contain min of 1 and max of 15 characters!"required/>
                    </spring:bind>
                    </td><td>
                        <p id="demo" cssClass="error" />
                        <springform:errors path="name" cssClass="error" />
                       </td></tr>

            <tr><th>Email</th><td>
                    <spring:bind path="cust.emailid">
                    <input name="emailid" type="email" id="emailid"  class="form-control"   value="${pdet.username}" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$" title="Please enter a valid email address." required size="40"/>
                    </spring:bind>
                    </td><td>
                        <p id="demo" cssClass="error" />
                        <springform:errors path="emailid" cssClass="error" />
                       </td><td style="border:0; color: red; position: fixed;">${msg}</td></tr>

             <tr><th>Mobile Number</th><td>
                    <spring:bind path="cust.mobileno">
                   <input name="mobileno" type="text" id="mobileno" class="form-control"  pattern="[0-9]{6,10}" title="Mobile number of minimum of 6 and maximum of 10 digits" value="${pdet.register_mno} " />

                    </spring:bind>
                    </td><td>
                        <p id="demo" cssClass="error" />
                        <springform:errors path="mobileno" cssClass="error" />
                       </td></tr>




               <tr><th>Description</th><td>
                    <spring:bind path="cust.description">
                    <textarea name="description" rows='3' id='description' class="form-control" title="cust_comment" required></textarea>
                    </spring:bind>
                    </td> </td><td>
                        <p id="demo" cssClass="error" />
                        <springform:errors path="description" cssClass="error" />
                       </td></tr>
```

@RestController code:

@RequestMapping(value="/customer/new", method= RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json" ) 
    public ResponseEntity addCustomer(@RequestBody feedbackRepo customer, UriComponentsBuilder ucb){

```
    feedback f=new feedback(); 
    customer.setName(f.getName());
    customer.setEmailid(f.getEmailid());

    this.pmService.saveCustomer(customer);
    HttpHeaders headers=new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setLocation(ucb.path("/customer/{id}").buildAndExpand(customer.getIssueid()).toUri());
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.CREATED);  
}
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the question to add since it is my very first post on stackoverflow.. My question is I am able to insert data in database using postman but I want to know how can I input data from front end i.e. from JSP page and save it in DB using Spring RESTful services. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send multipart form data from jsp to web service?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336113/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-from-jsp-to-web-service)