# Spring RESTful webservices Image/file upload/download from/to Database

Tags: spring, rest

I need help about steps for how to upload or Download a Image or File in Spring RESTful webservices

Comment: fallow this link you will have some clue . This link has example using Jersey hope it will be useful to you as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336113/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-from-jsp-to-web-service/43337311#43337311

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/